# Pros Vs Cons of using multiple div overlays instead of separate pages?

Tags: html

Out of curiosity what would be the pros vs cons of building a site that only uses an index.html page with multiple div overlays containing page contents that users can navigate through as opposed to making an individual HTML file for each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you would want to split the page into multiple files. A single page for a website using div overlays may make switching between pages faster, but increases load time and could make writing the page harder. Not everyone would use all the pages on your website.

**Div Overlays**

Pros:

- Faster load time between pages
- Pages can use JavaScript values from other pages

  - Quickly edit content based on changes in other pages

Cons:

- Large file size, slower initial load time
- Hard to read in some text editors

**Multiple files**

Pros:

- Fast initial load speed, smaller file size
- Each page is easier to read and edit

Cons:

- Slightly slower load speed when switching between pages
- Harder to share information between pages

---

It really depends on what kind of website you are making. If it's a small website that has pages that rely on other pages to work, use div overlays.

If it's a large website with many articles and pages, you should split it into multiple files.